# PlayFrameWork cannot override onHandlerNotFound

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to handle a 404 error in playframework with my own template. Play version is 2.2.0.

This is my code in the Global.java

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Results.notFound(views.html.page404.render());
    }
}
```

And this is the error it throws. What's the fix?

```
error: onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader) in Global cannot override onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader) in GlobalSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work for me by replacing the code in Globals.java with the following.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(internalServerError(views.html.page404.render()));
    }
}
```